# How to include the parent page link in this wp_nav_menu walker

Tags: menus

I've got a site with a sidebar of 'sub-navigation' I also need to have those links 'parent page' in the navigation also. So, for example I've got

Parent

child 1

child 2

child 3

but the php only gives me

child 1

child 2

child 3

the code is here -

```
<nav id="sub-navigation">
    <?php wp_nav_menu( array('theme_location' => 'main-navigation', 'container' => '', 'walker' => new Related_Sub_Items_Walker(), 'start_depth' => 1, 'include_parent' => 1, 'strict_sub' => 1, 'only_related' => 1, 'filter' => 0, 'filter_selection' => 0, ) ); ?>
</nav>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I need it 'within' the navigation due to how I've currently styled the look of it.

Answer (score 1):

WordPress does not have the class `Related_Sub_Items_Walker`. It looks like you're using the plugin [Advanced Menu Widget](http://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-menu-widget/).

Judging by the widget's source, you want to use 0 for the start_depth to include the parent. This is  untested.

```
<nav id="sub-navigation">
  <?php
    wp_nav_menu( array(
      'theme_location' => 'main-navigation',
       'container' => '',
       'walker' => new Related_Sub_Items_Walker(),
       'start_depth' => 0, // 0-indexed
       'include_parent' => 1,
       'strict_sub' => 1,
       'only_related' => 1,
       'filter' => 0,
       'filter_selection' => 0,
    ) );
  ?>
</nav>
```